# App removed from Play Store, Internal Test not working

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Our app has been removed from the Google Play Store due to an issue. The issue has been fixed and I'm trying to perform an internal test to see if it is working, its been a few hours and I'm not getting any email to notification to say that the app is ready for testing. It hasn't been pushed to my device either.

Does the app have to be live in the Play Store for the Internal test to work?

Comment: The fastest way for you to get an answer to this might be to chat with the Google Play support (available when you're logged in to the Google Play Developer Console; not sure about which hours of the day).

Comment: why? it has to do: it will help closing your question as off-topic faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for at least 24h because sometimes it takes longer than usual. Once when i published an app it took them 3h and the other time I had to wait for almost a day for them to publish. If you stil don't get response, write to google play support for more details.

Comment: Thanks Tomaz, I'll just have to wait so.

Comment: I really do believe that within 24h you will get your answer but if you do not, do not worry as I had similar situation with app removal and the support was realy kind! They helped me through and published my app once again!

Comment: Did the waiting help?